# Implementing logic on comparing two strings before processing further

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance, logic

I am trying to incorporate some logic into an application which will improve its performance but I simply can't wrap around a good way to implement it. So I have a set of json files which I deserialize from and all these files have the same structure.

```
{
urlSouce": """,
  "info": [
    {
      "id": ""
    }
]
}
```

So each time I Deserialize a file I urlSOurce in a variable and use that value for an API request. However I have understood that most of the time this urlSource is the same and hence keep sending an API request is not needed and affecting performance which is why I first want to check if the urlSource coming in from a currently deserializing file is the same as the previous file.

If so, there is no need to send the API request again . I understand I can us an boolean flag to add in this logic but I can't think of where is the best place to keep it.

To demonstrate what I am doing I have the following code. If anyone has any idea on what needs to be done please help me

```
string previousUrl;
string currentURL;
bool isValueChanged;

currentURL = "test1.com"; //the new URL populated from the deserialized JSON
previousUrl = "test2.com"; //the previously deserialized URL of the file before this
```

Here I have no problem with any of the deserialization

The problem I have is how do I keep track of the previousURl value ? and how can I manipulate the booleanFlag?

Comment: how are you receiving the data? are you doing one deserialization after next? if it is one after another, can you not simply compare the two strings and if they dont match, do something?

Comment: From what I can tell, you have multiple strings coming in and you want to determine if you've encountered one before. Is that correct?

Comment: yes @RufusL Exactly right

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to validate that a string has not been used previously before you process it.

If that's the case, you could simply store the "used" strings in a `Dictionary`, with the string as the `Key` and the result of processing as the `Value`, and then just check if the dictionary already contains a `Key` for any new strings before processing them.

The method below takes in a `string` to process and a `bool` specifying whether or not to use a cached result if it exists. If the `string` is not contained in the dictionary, or the user specifies `useCache = false`, the string is processed and saved in the dictionary (along with the result), and the result is returned. Otherwise the cached result for that string is returned right away.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> cachedResults = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public string GetApiResult(string uri, bool useCachedResult = true)
{
    // If we've already encountered this string, return the cached result right away
    if (useCachedResult && cachedResults.ContainsKey(uri)) return cachedResults[uri];

    // Process the string here
    var result = MakeAPICall(uri);

    // Save it, along with the result, in our dictionary
    cachedResults[uri] = result;

    // Return the result
    return result;
}
```

---

It sounds like I misunderstood the question. If you're only trying to determine if a new string matches the last string encountered, then that's also very simple:

```
private string cachedUri;
private string cachedResult;

public string GetApiResult(string uri, bool useCachedResult = true)
{
    // If we've already encountered this string, return the cached result right away
    if (useCachedResult && uri == cachedUri) return cachedResult;

    // Process the string here
    var result = MakeAPICall(uri);

    // Save it, along with the result, in our fields
    cachedUri = uri;
    cachedResult = result;

    // Return the result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: there is a small problem here. So say the first time I get test1.com as the Url and the 2nd time also I get test1.com but the third time I get a newUrl test2.com and the fourth time I get test1.com again.

In such a case I would need to make the api request the first time and since the seond time its the same url i sholdn't send an api request . however thrid time it has changed again so I must make a new API request. but in the fourth time even though it is a url we have encontered before it is not the most latest url we had ... So I would want to make an API request again

Comment: I must have misunderstood - I asked if "you want to determine if you've encountered one before" and you said "exactly right". But it sounds like you only want to know if the new string matches the last string encountered?

Comment: I added another sample that only compares to the last encountered `Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `MemoryCache` (or just `Dictionary`) with Url as a key and response's result as value, but if there usually just one url variables as you have could be enough:

```
string previousUrl = null;
string previousValue = null;
string currentURL;
bool isValueChanged;

while (…)
{
   string result = null;
   currentURL = "test1.com"; //the new URL populated from the deserialized JSON
   if (previousUrl != currentUrl)
   {
      previousResult = GetTheData(currentUrl);
      previousUrl = currentUrl;
   }
   result = previousResult;

   // process result for currentUrl 
}
```